# Unit Testing a Task<ViewResult>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, xunit

Previously, I had a synchronous controller action method that had a unit test with the line

```
ManageBillsViewModel result = controller.ManageBills(2).ViewData.Model as ManageBillsViewModel;
```

and all was well. When the action method was changed to an asynchronous `Task<ViewResult>` method, the above line broke.

I thought I could get it working by adding `.Result` as in

```
ManageBillsViewModel result = controller.ManageBills(2).Result.ViewData.Model as ManageBillsViewModel;
```

but this did not work.

How can I appropriately access the `ViewData.Model` of an asynchronous method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the code async all the way down and `await` the `Task<ViewResult>` returned from invoking the controller action. The test would also need to made async as well.

```
[Fact]
public async Task MyTestMethod() {

    //...

    //Act
    var viewResult = await controller.ManageBills(2); 

    ManageBillsViewModel result = viewResult.ViewData.Model as ManageBillsViewModel;

    //Assert

    //...
}
```

Blocking calls like `.Result` and `.Wait()` can lead to deadlocks and should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

async methods return tasks, you can use

```
var task = controller.ManageBills(2);
task.Wait();
var result = task.Result;
```

or

```
var result = await controller.ManageBills(2);
```